# Can you 'break' a for loop in AmpScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to know if its possible to break a FOR loop in AmpScript. I am traversing through a rowset and would like to stop on the first match.

```
SET @BookingRowset = LookupOrderedRows("bookings", 200, "booking_timestamp Asc", "user_id", @AccountId)
SET @BookingsRows = RowCount(@BookingRowset)

IF @BookingsRows >= 1 THEN
for @cnt = 1 to @BookingsRows do

    SET @BRow = row(@BookingRowset, @cnt)
    SET @booking_timestamp = field(@BRow,"booking_timestamp")

    IF (@booking_timestamp < NOW()) THEN
      // FOUND THE RECORD, DO SOMETHING TO BREAK LOOP AND CONTINUE
    ENDIF

NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
```

Comment: have you tried comparing timestamp in LookupOrderedRows and just set the no of rows to import as 1. LookupOrderedRows("bookings", 1, "booking_timestamp Asc", "user_id", $AccountId, "booking_timestamp", ($booking_timestamp < NOW())) Please set the $booking_timestamp before the lookup..also i have used $to set variable cause the comments don't allow actual symbol

Comment: @BradSapkota - you should write this as an answer. It is a simple solution to the problem that doesn't even require the for loop.

Comment: If it works then that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any manipulation of the variable declared for the for loop value will throw an error:

> "The variable @i is in use by a processing loop and cannot be declared
>   or set."

This means that inside the FOR loop you are unable to manipulate the variable to break or exit a For Loop early.

You could do something along the lines of adding a new variable in and when you want to 'break' it, set this variable to 'true'.  This then removes all outputs of the for loop, despite it still running.

See below for example:

```
%%[ 

    for @i = 1 to 5 do

    IF @break != 'true' THEN

          OUTPUT(CONCAT('Loop # ', @i, '<br /><br />'))

          if @i == 1 THEN

             SET @break = 'true'

          endif 
    ENDIF

    next @i
]%%
```

This will output:

```
Loop # 1
```

Comment: Hello @HamishWilson - I was very confused with your answer and example, which is why I created my answer. I provided insight into WHY it cannot be broken and a simple example of what needs to be done to only collect a single record. Just because answers are similar does not make them the same.

Comment: I respect your right to an opinion and all, but let's just drop it and move on with differing opinions. This is a forum to help people, not argue.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a while and I don't think there is a way. You can always set a counter in your loop. When the conditions to the IF statement are met then add 1 to the counter so you effectively only act upon the first result:

```
SET @counter = 0

IF @BookingsRows >= 1 THEN
for @cnt = 1 to @BookingsRows do

    SET @BRow = row(@BookingRowset, @cnt)
    SET @booking_timestamp = field(@BRow,"booking_timestamp")

    IF (@booking_timestamp < NOW()) AND @counter < 1 THEN
      @counter = Add(@counter,1)
    ENDIF

NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
```

If you really need a break then try using SSJS to handle the data as you can use 'break' to terminate a loop. Hope this helps!